# How can I create in robotframework a keyword with a for loop that applies arguments to its iterations?

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

I'm working with Robot Framework and can create a loop that checks certain pages of my website. In this loop I can do several checks. Example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check all cat pages
  Get all cats
  :FOR  ${cat}  IN  ${cats}
  /  Go to catpage  ${cat}
  /  Check if page has  ${cat}
  /  Check if page is fluffy
  /  Check if page haz burger

*** Keywords ***
Get all cats
  [some irrelevant magic that gives me all cats]

Go to catpage
  [Arguments]  ${cat}
  Go to  ${SERVER}/catpages/${cat}.html

Check if page has
  [Arguments]  ${cat}
  [do some irrelevant magic with the variable ${cat}]

Check if page is fluffy
  [do some irrelevant magic]

Check if page haz burger
  [do some irrelevant magic]
```

Now, I want to actually have the for-loop part in a separate keyword that I can call, after which the checks will be applied to each iteration of the loop, like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check if the cats are fluffy
  Check all cat pages
    [Check if page is fluffy]

Check what the cats have
  Check all cat pages
    [Check if page has  ${cat}]
    [Check if page haz burger]

*** Keywords ***
Check all cat pages
  Get all cats
  :FOR  ${cat}  IN  ${cats}
  /  Go to catpage  ${cat}
  /  [the keywords applied here]

  [...]
```

So, in the second example the for-loop would be applied twice. First it would loop over all the catpages, and check for each catpage how fluffy it is. At the second loop it would iterate again over all catpages, and check if each catpage has ${cat}, ánd if it haz burger. Of course I could write for both test cases a new for-loop, but to keep things readable I would rather call a keyword with the loop and apply some keywords to it. I then would be able to add new keywords easily (for example, if I create a new keyword like 'Check if page has photo', I can add it to the 'Check what the cats have' test, and all pages will then be checked if it has a photo.

How can I achieve such a setup?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a list of keywords (eg: `["check if the cats are fluffy", "check what the cats have"]`, and then be able to run each of those keywords for every page?

Comment: Hm, maybe it was the Friday afternoon, but I hadn't thought of creating a list of the different keywords and then use that list as a variable to give to the keyword that contains the for-loop to use on every page. Let me try that. How does it work when a keyword in the list requires a variable by itself, like ["check if page has ${cat}"]?

Comment: You can make all your custom keywords expect all possible variables (but use only the ones you need). In this case, you could just iterate the list of keywords and do `Run Keyword  ${kw}  ${cat}  ${cat_size}  ${cat_color}`

Comment: Let us know if this works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay: weekend, other tasks at work and a national holiday got in the way. Thank you Brian Oakley and jim: you set me on the right path. I also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218660/modifying-lists-of-lists-in-robot-framework) to help me get to the right answer.

I use a few steps. First I create a new keyword for the keyword I want to use:

```
*** Keywords ***
Check if page has
[Arguments]  ${cat}
[do some irrelevant magic with the variable ${cat}]

Use check if page has
${Task1} =  convert to string  Check if page has
${Task2} =  convert to string  ${cat}
${TasksCombined} =  create list  ${Task1}  ${Task2}
set suite variable  ${CatTask}  ${TasksCombined}
```

Now I can use the sentence 'Use check if page has' to get a list with the name of this keyword and the variable.

Next I create two loops:

```
*** Keywords ***
Loop over all pages
  [Arguments]  ${TasksToPerform}
  Get all cats
  :FOR  ${kitten}  IN  ${cats}
  \  set suite variable  ${cat}  ${kitten}
  \  Go to catpage  ${cat}
  \  Loop over tasks  ${TasksToPerform}

Loop over tasks
  [Arguments]  ${TasksToPerform}
  ${AmountTasks} =  get length  ${TasksToPerform}
  :FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  0  ${AmountTasks}
  \  ${Task} =  get from list  ${TasksToPerform}  ${index}
  \  ${TaskLength} =  get length  ${Task}
  \  run keyword if  '${TaskLength}' == '1'  ${Task[0]}
  \  ...  ELSE IF  '${TaskLength}' == '2'  ${Task[0]}  ${Task[1]}
  \  ...  ELSE IF  '${TaskLength}' == '3'  ${Task[0]}  ${Task[1]}  ${Task[2]}
```

In the first loop I get all the different cats, go to the corresponding cat page and run the second loop. This second loop first determines how many tasks there are to perform. Then it loops over all of them. For each task it checks how many arguments the task has, and runs the task (the first element of the array should always be the keyword) along with up to two keywords (you could make more: is there a way to make this dynamically?).
Ow, and by setting the variable ${cat} as a suite variable, I can replace in the keywords themselves the local 'cat'-variable by the ${cat} that is generated in the first loop.
These keywords allow me to create these tests:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check if the cats are fluffy
  Use check if page is fluffy
  @{TasksToPerform} =  create list  ${FluffyTask}
  Loop over tasks  ${TasksToPerform}

Check what the cats have
  Use check if page has
  Use check if page haz burger
  @{TasksToPerform} =  create list  ${CatTask}  ${BurgerTask}
  Loop over tasks  ${TasksToPerform}
```

In these tests I first lists all the tests I want to perform for that loop, then group the lists for those specific tests together in one big list and loop over that. This allows me to assign a number of tests to the loops, and expand it further if I make more tests.

Once again, thanks for the pointers, guys!